# PostgreSQL is not listening on IPv4:5432 in docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am working with postgres:10.3 inside Docker (18.03.1-ce) and everything was OK until today when it unexpectedly stopped listening on ipv4. I have not changed any database configuration. Instead of displaying

> listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432

in the logs, it shows now

> listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Command `netstat -a`:

```
Proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address     Foreign Address    State  
tcp    0       0       127.0.0.11:41441  0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN     
udp    0       0       localhost:47558   localhost:47558    ESTABLISHED
udp    0       0       127.0.0.11:33252  0.0.0.0:*                          

Proto RefCnt Flags    Type    State      I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]  STREAM  LISTENING  943382   /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

pg_hba.conf contents:

```
TYPE    DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
local   replication     all                                     trust

host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

Inside postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I am not exposing any ports outside postgres container. The services communicate with each other within Docker Swarm.

Comment: The part about the Unix socket is normal, I have the same socket line apart from the I-node. However, I also have the IP address line 'tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN'. Have you tried other IP addresses, or added anything else that listens on the same one?

Comment: Your pg_hba.conf looks normal. My local communication works fine with the listen_addresses in postgresql.conf commented out. Probably nothing wrong with the parts of the configuration that you posted.

Comment: I have just checked the flow of postgres startup and it goes like this:
-> listening on unix socket
-> docker-entrypoint-initdb.d execution (here i have scripts that require localhost:5432)
-> shut down
-> listening on "0.0.0.0", port 5432
-> listening on unix socket.
So, eventually postgres starts listening on tcp, but not initially. When I run image postgres:10 (downloaded a few days ago) on another computer, it works fine.

Comment: I still don't know what causes the problem, but I temporarily fixed it by installing postgres:10.2

Comment: Please provide your `Dockerfile` and/or `docker-compose.yml`.